# SQL Server : use of of & in String function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in mid of decoding a SQL Server query, which is like

```
select , Trim([Type1] & [Type2] & [Type3]) AS Type from table_name
```

I learned `&` is a bitwise operator but could not get what is it working inside a function which operates on string. Also datatype of `Type 1`, `Type 2`, `Type 3` is string.

Comment: This should give you a good rundown of how the & operator is used in sql and also why the way you are trying to use it is failing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx

Comment: I don't get this... What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you should give an example of input values (Type1, Type2 and Typ3) and the expected output (edit them into your question).

Comment: @HanoJohannesRossouw As mentioned in link "Performs a bitwise logical AND operation between two integer values.", In my case Type 1, Type 2, Type 3 are String and i could not get the behaviour of & operator with String.

Comment: @Sid hope it solved your question

Comment: Are you just attempting to concatenate a string? If so, use the + operator instead of &

Comment: Looks like someone has copied Visual Basic code directly to SQL. `&` in VB is string concatenation, thereby you can use `+` instead (like Mark E already noted).

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, its not really clear what the query is doing, but there are several issues with the query as it is:

The varchar and nvarchar datatypes are not compatible with the & operator.

i.e.

```
select 'and' & 'but'
```

if type1, type2 and type 3 are varchars like '1', '2', '3' you could cast them:

```
select convert(int,'75') & convert(int, '175').
```

Also 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: About `trim()` - in SQL server you have to use `ltrim(rtrim())`. Another VB influence :)